# Do the isomorphism classes of fiber bundles constitute a set?

Tags: set-theory, manifolds, fiber-bundles

Let $ M $  and $ F $ be smooth manifolds. Is the collection of 
isomorphism classes of fiber bundles of fiber type $ F $ over $ M $ a set or not and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each such fibre bundle has cardinality $|M|\times|F|$. So take a set of this
size, consider the set of all topologies on it, and for each topology, consider the
set of all continuous functions to $M$ which have the structure of fibre bundle with fibre $F$. You get a set of fibre bundles which contain representatives
of each isomorphism class of bundle.